# Where is the BSurfaces project living now?

Tags: add-on

It would appear that www.BSurfaces.info the web site for the retopologizing tool has gone down and was gobbled up by a dentistry practice. Where is the project living now? Has someone put the code on Github? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though the site is gone we still have the addon. In fact it comes with the default blender. Just search in the addons for *bsurfaces*. Or if you are looking for the code go to the addon folder in the blender directory `2.71\scripts\addons\mesh_bsurfaces.py`.

There are still a few places to get info about Bsurfaces.

1. The [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5)
2. [Blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?225190-Bsurfaces-v1-5)
3. A great [PDF](https://app.box.com/s/5ygw6vkzxkag9dh53uuv) linked from the blender wiki
4. A few videos from the creator of Bsurfaces on [vimeo](http://vimeo.com/user572057/videos)
5. Blender cookie tutorial on BSurfaces [here](https://vimeo.com/27353774).

Comment: Is the version that ships with Blender the fully featured BSurfaces? As I remember, the GPL version wasn't as beefy as the "real" version. Thanks for the info about where to find the python script.

Comment: @WrayBowling I think the version of bsurfaces that is in blender (v1.5) is as full featured as it gets. v1.2 was that last version that he charged for. As I remember he was only charging money up to a certain amount, then he released the whole scrip as GPL.