# Bsurfaces addon not working correctly

Tags: add-on, topology, grease-pencil

I am trying to retopolize my mesh using the grease pencil and the [Bsurfaces addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16204/2217), but I keep getting this error.

the retopology is not setting correctly.

Instead of getting a ring of square, I get two highly subdivided loops instead. How can I make grease pencil retopolgy work correctly on a sculpted icosphere?

Oh and I keep getting a message (image below).

[image: error message]

When I follow this method an new object is created as well called 'SUFSKIO' (image below). How can I fix this?

[image: objects in outliner]

Answer (score 4):

I just tested the Bsurfaces addon (version 1.5) with blender version 2.75a and it is completely functional (with a bug that disables *Global Undo*).

However there are a few things you need to be sure of to get it to work.

1. Set the grease pencil source to *Object* (this is your problem)
   [image: grease pencil settings]
   The tool tip even says that it is needed for Bsurfaces to work.
   [image: tool tip]
2. For best results draw the strokes in *Object* mode.
   However if you drew in edit mode and it looks like this:
   [image: bad grease pencil strokes on surface]
   You can click on the *Enable Editing* button in the *Grease Pencil* tab of the tool shelf.
   Or you can click the *Edit Strokes* button. It is in the *Tools* tab of the tool shelf.
   [image: Edit Strokes button]
   I prefer the latter because you can simple delete the bad points, and not bother with trying to reposition them.
3. Save often, as in before you start Bsurfaces and after you create every piece you are happy with. You will still find bugs.

---

Last I would refer you to [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16205/2217) on resources for Bsurfaces, there is a great PDF, that is still very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Bsurfaces is no longer being maintained, and so has started to have a variety of problems in more recent blender versions. I believe it started breaking somewhere in the 2.6x's. I do not know if your problem specifically is due to this, but it's likely. If it is, then it's not a user error.

From looking at bsurfaces's thread on blender artists, it looks like some people in the community have been updating it. Check out this thread: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?225190-Bsurfaces-v1-5/page21