# How to Convert GPencil strokes to Bsurface Mesh without errors?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, grease-pencil

The idea was to use this script below from [Convert Curves to Grease Pencil?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/convert-curves-to-grease-pencil) to generate gpencil strokes from curves (poly spline type) and use them with a Bsurfaces addon (ver 1.5) to make a mesh in Blender 2.74.

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
def convert_curve_to_gp(obj):
    #---- CHANGED ----
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    mesh = obj.data
    layer = scene.grease_pencil.layers.new("layer", set_active=True)
    frame = layer.frames.new(scene.frame_current)
    #---- /CHANGED ----
    mesh = obj.to_mesh(scene, apply_modifiers=False, settings='PREVIEW')
    for edge in mesh.edges:
        stroke = frame.strokes.new()
        stroke.draw_mode = '3DSPACE'
        stroke.points.add(2)
        stroke.points[0].co = obj.matrix_world * Vector(mesh.vertices[edge.vertices[0]].co)
        stroke.points[1].co = obj.matrix_world * Vector(mesh.vertices[edge.vertices[1]].co)
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)

obj = bpy.context.object
convert_curve_to_gp(obj)
```

When *Bsurfaces* is used by clicking on its *Add surface* button it generates an error:

> AttributeError: 'GPENCIL_OT_SURFSK_add_surface' object has no attribute 'original_curve'

and it creates a new curve object.

Comment: See if [my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36635/2217) helps. Different problem, but may help.