# Convert grease pencil disabled

Tags: grease-pencil

I´m stuck here. I need to convert what I just drew with the grease pencil to curve/mesh (don´t know exactly the term) so I can connect it afterwards to the mesh above. I´ve been looking around and I found that maybe the convert button could help me doing what I´m trying to do, but as you can see it is disabled. How can I enable it? or if there´s a more effective way to do what I intend to, what is it? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide in this matter :)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in Edit mode of the mesh. If you want to convert Grease Pencil layer into curves / mesh you need to exit Edit mode of any other object. Or you can use Bsurface addon to convert GP drawing into the mesh right in Edit mode on the fly.

**Simple Converting Grease Pencil drawing**

Once something is drawn on the mesh, exit Edit mode of the mesh (the Edit mode of Grease Pencil may be left on) and choose *Convert* in the *Toolshelf* > *Grease Pencil*. You'll have options to choose that you want it to convert to - *Path*, *Bezier Curve* or *Polygon Curve*.

- [Converting sketches to geometry](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/grease_pencil/converting_to_geometry.html)
- [Drawing with Grease Pencil](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/grease_pencil/drawing.html#drawing-with-grease-pencil)

**Convert Grease Pencil in Edit mode**

Use [Bsurfaces addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16204/where-is-the-bsurfaces-project-living-now) to use Grease Pencil as retopo tool and convert it into mesh surface while in Edit mode.
After [enabling addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon) create some simple mesh, enter Edit mode and delete its vertices. After that, draw with Grease Pencil and once finished, in the *Toolshelf* > *Tools* > *BSurfaces* rollout press *Add Surface* to convert your strokes to surface.

[image: convert Grease pencil drawing to mesh surface]

The Bsurface needs either 2 Grease Pencil strokes (shown above) or one stroke and one selection of geometry (below). To make strokes drawn with Grease Pencil to connect to already existing surface draw a stroke, select the edge loop of that surface which is the nearest to the stroke and then proceed to *Add Surface*.

[image: adding stroke by bsurface]

Watch [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VC98kiy10Q) on more techniques about using this functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I can use bsurfaces. But my question is...(don´t know how to explain myself) how do I construct from there? I mean, suppose you draw with the grease pencil and add surface to it, and then you do the same next to it, how do you connect those surfaces? I tried selecting the vertices of both surfaces´s ends and pressed J to join, but they don´t join each other :( thank you a lot for your effort trying to help me. Sorry I´m so dumb :(

Comment: @MatCav edited the answer. This techinque is mentioned in the video which is quite detailed on using the addon.

Comment: Oh! sorry I didn´t watch it. I´ll do it...my bad.